# Onde e quando AngularJS é adequado usar?

Tags: angularjs, angular

1. O AngularJS serve bem para aplicações de médio/grande porte?
2. Apenas o AngularJS já é o suficiente para desenvolver uma aplicação?
3. A aplicação pode se tornar mais difícil de realizar manutenções futuras? (como acontece com aplicações PWA).
4. Posso hospedar em qualquer hospedagem ou possui algum específico?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

> O AngularJS serve bem para aplicações de médio/grande porte?

Serve. Na verdade não há uma relação direta entre uma coisa e outra. E ainda teria que definir o que é uma aplicação de médio ou grande porte, garanto que cada pessoa tem uma definição diferente. O que eu diria é que não deveria usar para algo muito simples e pensar melhor para algo que não seja muito complexo e que seria uma aplicação web e não um *website*.

> Apenas o AngularJS já é o suficiente para desenvolver uma aplicação?

Não, afinal AngularJS é só um *framework* que te ajuda fazer algumas coisas no *frontend*. Não faz tudo ali, e não resolve o problema do *backend*, não é toda infraestrutura necessária.

> A aplicação pode se tornar mais difícil de realizar manutenções futuras? (como acontece com aplicações PWA).

Não sei de onde vem essa ideia. Novamente teria que definir o que é difícil. Em algum aspecto se torna mais difícil, em outro se torna mais fácil. No fundo o jeito que você faz é que determinará a dificuldade. Se você for um programador ingênuo provavelmente fará algo ruim. Só uma dica, suas perguntas soam ingênuas, então pense bem se o problema não está mais embaixo.

Nem sei de problemas que está falando de PWA (pelo menos problemas que não tem em outra forma que faça a mesma coisa ou que não seja inerente à escolha feita).

> Posso hospedar em qualquer hospedagem ou possui algum específico?

Sim, até porque ele não vai rodar na sua hospedagem, é um *framework* de *frontend* que nada tem a ver com hospedagem. Até existe a possibilidade de usar no *backend*, mas em geral isso é adicional e não só, além de ser opcional e raramente usado.

Parece que está procurando respostas mágicas que te fazem decidir o que usar. Isto não dá certo, assim qualquer decisão será errada. Precisa entender profundamente tudo para tomar uma decisão adequada. Está olhando para o problema errado.

Qualquer pessoa que se dê bem com programação vai se resolver bem com qualquer tecnologia e ela perceberá onde está se metendo porque ela tem base. Se a pessoa não está preparada para isto qualquer tecnologia será uma dor de cabeça e ela sofrerá, então a solução é aprender de forma adequada em vez só escolher que tecnologia usar e começar usar sem entender o que está fazendo.

Eu pensei antes de responder porque essas respostas são válidas, mas não ajudam muito e pode até parecer que resolve algum problema saber essas coisas. Quem obtém essa informação por consequência do aprendizado usará de uma forma melhor. Lendo esta resposta parece claro que deve usar Angular (e espero que esteja usando uma versão do Angular e não do AngularJS que está obsoleto), mas eu que tenho bastante experiência com programação não uso.